# Recurring Records with Specified Recurrence + Termination Date in ActiveRecord / PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

#### Problem

Hello. I have a model with a field of the format 'datetime' with the name :date. I also have a field in this model of the format 'string' with the name :recurrence. I'd like to be able to set these models to recur say "every week" "every 3 weeks" "every month", etc and also specify a termination date repeat "every week" ending in "4 months". All fields (except for :date) will remain the same on recurring records.

#### Question

Is there a Gem to assist with this type of development or example available? I can't find anything of this sort on the internet or in the IRC chat rooms.

Any assistance on this matter would be **greatly** appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

check the gem [ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) or [recurrence](https://github.com/EdvardM/recurrence), they provides exactly what you mentioned.